# Connecting an Existing Facebook Page with a Facebook App

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk

1) I already have a Facebook Page for my product here: http://www.facebook.com/portfoliopro

Previously my iPad app didn't integrate with Facebook. But in my next update it does and enables user to upload photos to Facebook.

2) So now I also have a Facebook "App". ie I've integrated Facebook's iOS SDK into my app and I have an app id.

Rather than make a new Facebook community page for my app from scratch I'd like to connect the Facebook App with the existing Facebook Page.

Is this possible? I can't see how having looked through the settings for both the app and the page extensively.

Answer (score 1):

It happens automatically when you create your Facebook app page. However, if you remove it, it is disconnected forever.